# Harmonic Oscillators - Statistical Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

"Consider a system with L states of discrete energy. Assume that the fundamental level energy, E0, has a degeneracy of M:

(a) Show that for high temperatures, the average energy is equal to the average energy of the L states. Also, show that the entropy is : S = Kln(L)"

How to solve this? I don't know where to begin.

Here's what i got using the Partition Function to find the avg. of the energy:[image]

Edit:

Is this it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Physics stack exchange! Actually homework questions are not very appreciated, so at least you have to show some effort to solve the problem.   I try to help you: So you have to find out how the energy is distributed over the L states of different energy. So what is the distribution to be used in this case ?

Comment: It's the Canonical Esemble, i'm using the Gibbs Distribution. But i'm not sure where the L states fits.
The energy of a given state l is El = hw(1/2 + l) , l = 0,1,2 ... L?
Then, the prob to find an oscilator on a state is : Pl = (1/Z)e^(El/KT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to suppose anything on the system (not necessarily harmonic oscillator for instance). Indeed, for sufficiently high temperature $\left(T \gg \max \limits_{k = 1 ... L} (E_k)- \min \limits_{k = 1 ... L} (E_k)\right)$, all states have the same probability to occur (regardless of their energy, but up to degeneracy). From here, you can try to find the mean energy and the entropy of the system, knowing that all states are equiprobable.

Comment: I was thinking about using the partition function. The average energy is the derivate of the -log(partition function), but i got the weird result that the average energy was 2/(1 + E0 + 2L)

Comment: You can use the partition function, yes (even if IMHO working directly with probabilities is simpler in that case). Start by writing explicitely the derivative of the partition function WRT $\beta$, you should find something like $\frac{\Sigma E_k \exp(-\beta E_k)}{\Sigma \exp(-\beta E_k)}$. Now take $\beta \to 0$ and... I will let you figure out the rest :)

Comment: Also if I got your notation correctly your result does not seem homogeneous. There must be a $\hbar \omega$ missing. Note that the result you are asked to derivate would still hold for any system with a finite number of states, so you don't especially need to write the partition function for a harmonic oscillator to find the answer.

Comment: So, i got as result the sum of the energys from the state 0 to L, divided by L+1 states, is this it?

Comment: Yes ! (well, depending on wether you start from $0$ or $1$ you have either $L+1$ or $L$ states but that's the spirit). It is what the question formulates as "the average energy of the states". Your second picture looks correct.